# "Mongod" works, but running "rails console" results in "Failed to connect to a master node at 127.0.0.1:9100 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, rubygems, mongomapper

I have a problem with MongoDB.

For a start, when running `mongod`, and then `mongo` (in another teminal window), I get:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: test
> 
>
```

However. When I type `rails console` in my Heroku app terminal, I get:

```
Failed to connect to a master node at 127.0.0.1:9100 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
from /Users/musetr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/connection.rb:594:in `setup'
from /Users/musetr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/connection.rb:130:in `initialize'
from /Users/mmusetr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:79:in `new'
from /Users/musetr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:79:in `connect'
from /Users/musetr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:89:in `setup'
```

..
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does Ruby need to be running?

Comment: Can you post the mongod shell window output?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Mongod output: MacBook-Air-M:~ musetr$ mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without port options, both mongod and mongo use the default port number 27017.  The output from your rails console reports that it is trying to connect to port 9100.  Please check your MongoMapper configuration in config/mongo.yml, correlated with your checking of environment variable RAILS_ENV.